# Edit the content of a flash file

Tags: flash

I have some links in a .SWF file that I would like to remove because they are depricated.
Is there any way to do it?
I have downloaded something called "Flash Decompiler" but it is only a Demo and it does not allow me to remove things, but rather edit images etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.swf files are completed, compiled and published files that cannot be edited with Adobe Flash. However, many '.swf decompilers' do exist, for example take a look at this tutorial: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=70

Comment: Does it mean I have to decompile it and then run the .fla file with some editing software? or do i edit directly from a SWF decompiler?

Answer (score 1):

swf files cannot be edited directly.Convert the swf file into the source file.Source file basically decompiles the swf files and break it into the text,images or other things that you have used to make the swf file.Once you have the separate things you can edit them and again compile and make your swf file.

This is the best tool that i found to do everything that you need to do in the swf file:
1.Flash Decompiler Trillix(you need to buy this)
2.jpexs free flash decompiler (free and opensource)

Hope this will help you.